# No-operation scope in Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, syntax, scope

In C, I can do

```
int scoped_var = 2;
{
    int scoped_var = 3;
}
```

How do I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to have a block local variable named the same as a variable in the scope the block is defined in without setting the previously-defined variable, you can use this syntax:

```
foo = 1
items.each do |item;foo|
  foo = item.number
end
puts foo #=> 1
```

You can also do this without passing a block variable:

```
x = Proc.new { |;foo| ... }
```

Note that this is Ruby 1.9+ only.

Comment: @MichaelSlade I don't know that this is in the docs, which mostly just cover the methods in core and the standard library. I may have picked this up from a book, and I know the release logs for the first several 1.9.x releases that detailed the changes since 1.8.7 noted block local variables, but I doubt they went into examples.

Comment: An up-to-date language ref sure would be nice huh :/

Comment: There's [RubySpec](http://rubyspec.org/) if you want a reference, but otherwise I don't think there it makes economic sense to get the official documentation up to 100% coverage. I know I wouldn't bother reading it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something Ruby really does.  Locals are created by assignment; there simply is no way to declare them except as parameters. (And in 1.9, this includes block parameters.)

I suppose the Rubyish way to do a similar thing would just be to save and restore to another local via assignment.

Comment: Referring to my answer, these aren't *really* parameters…you can't pass arguments to be assigned for them. They're strictly for scoping.